# Getting predicted value Y to a certain number of X values in tensorflow.js

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm a beginner with machine learning and since i love to work with javascript, i recently started working with tensorflow.js Library. And i worked with both *Fitting the curve to the synthetic data* which is a **regression** problem and *MNIST digit recognition* with Convolutional layers which is a **classification** problem and now i kind of know how data flows through the layers.

But now i want to do more with the library. So i downloaded the *wine-quality.csv* dataset from open datasets which contains different quantities of components in the wine and which evaluates to a certain quality of the wine. The parsed data from .csv looks somewhat like this.

```
xs : [[5]]
ys : [[0.5,0.004,0.003,0.1,4,0.11]]
```

Now i want to pass the quantities (**YS**) of the wine to the model and i want the model to predict me the quality(**XS**) of the wine. And i have no idea how to Architect the idea. How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input array are of dimension 1 and of size 6. One can define the following model using a stochastic gradient descent optimizer.

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

// First define the model
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [6]}));
// use the sgd optimizer
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
const x = tf.tensor2d([[0.5,0.004,0.003,0.1,4,0.11]])
const y = tf.tensor2d([[5]])
//training data
model.fit(x, y)
//test data
model.predict(tf.tensor2d([0.5,0.004,0.003,0.1,4,0.11], [1, 6])).print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it required to normalize the input values `YS` before feeding to the model? And what happens if i don't normalize them?

Comment: @VelanSalis what do you mean by normalizing the input values ?

Comment: Squishing all the input values to the range of 1 to 0 or -1 to 1 probably. Is that required? Or does the activation function does that anyway? I'm a beginner with this system so i always stumble upon questions like this.

Comment: @VelanSalis, no the activation function does not center the data around a 0 mean. Though the zero-centering is not required, it is done whenever possible because it accelerates the convergence and the data could become easier to work with

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @edkeveked. That was a great help :)